# Find object in db.ListField (BaseList)

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have a model as below:

```
class Primary(db.Document):
    primaryName = db.StringField(required=True, max_length=20)
    secondaries = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Secondary))

class Secondary(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    secondaryName = db.StringField(required=True, max_length=20)
    secondarySurname = db.StringField(max_length=20)
```

I want to get an object of *Secondary* with a certain name or create it if it doesn't exist. So far I haven't found a better way than this:

```
# get the object if it exists already. Create otherwise
targetSecondary = None
for curSecondary in primary.secondaries:
    if curSecondary.secondaryName == 'targetName':
        targetSecondary = curSecondary
        break
if not targetSecondary:
    targetSecondary = Secondary(secondaryName='targetName')
    primary.secondaries.append(targetSecondary)
targetSecondary.secondarySurname = 'blahblah'
```

I wonder if there is a better way (I'm almost sure there is), would be nice if it was just some ready method from MongoEngine I don't know about yet. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your question but you can use something like isinstance function to check if its the instance of some class.

You can use `isinstance()` to check if that certain name is the instance of your desired class

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> a = None
>>> b = A()
>>> isinstance(a,A)
False
>>> isinstance(b,A)
True
>>>
```

If you get `False` i guess you can create the instance then.

Comment: Though I don't see how I can use it in this case, your code is interesting to me, I could use it somewhere else. Thank you for your suggestion, kingsdeb.

Comment: @makaron, Are you trying to check if "targetSecondary" is an instance of Secondary class or is it that "targetsecondary" is always an instance of Secondary class if it exists ? Disclaimer: I have never used mongodb

Comment: It's always an instance of that class :)